# Is there a way to reference an array index dynamically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm building a flashcard app for my English/Chinese dictionary in Vue 3 and when the user clicks a button I want the next item to show on the screen from the imported flashcards array.

Without having to iterate through the array with a for loop and pause the iteration until the user clicks a button, I want to simply grab the item in the array by it's index by setting a count -

```
<script>
  import flashcards from '../flashcards/flashcards.json';
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        count: 0,
        currentTranslation: {
          chinese: flashcards[this.count].traditional,
        },
      }
      },
      methods: {
        correctClickHandler() {
          this.setNextTranslation()
        },
        incorrectClickHandler() {
          this.setNextTranslation()
        },
        setNextTranslation() {
          this.count++
        }

    }
  }
</script>
```

When one of the click handlers is called, the count should increment by one and then the next item in the flashcards array should show.

Referencing `this.count` as an array index returns an undefined error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'traditional')
```

Why isn't `flashcards[this.count].traditional` the same as `flashcards[0].traditional` when `this.count` has already been set to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not what you think it is inside `data`. To be specific, it's not a reference to the current Vue instance, which is true for `methods` or `computed` functions. It's the `data` function's `this` and therefore none of the instance properties or methods are available on it.

In your case, to retain `currentTranslation` dependency on `this.count`, it should be a computed:

```html
<script>
  import flashcards from '../flashcards/flashcards.json';
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        count: 0
      }
    },
    computed: {
      currentTranslation() {
        return flashcards[this.count].traditional
      }
    },
    methods: {
      correctClickHandler() {
        this.setNextTranslation()
      },
      incorrectClickHandler() {
        this.setNextTranslation()
      },
      setNextTranslation() {
        this.count++
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your explanation above the code doesn't really _explain_ anything. Could you elaborate on that a little more for others who might want to understand your train of thoughts?

Comment: I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @tao This solved my issue. Thank you. What does ```this``` refer to in ```data()```? Does it refer to anything?

Comment: It varies based on Vue version. In Vue2 it used to be an ExtendedComponentInstance, but other than the typical internals starting with `_` or `$`, you wouldn't find much on it when `data` was run, as it didn't contain any `computed`, `methods` or reactive props yet. In Vue3, if `data` is a normal function, `this` is an empty object. If `data` is an anonymous function, `this` is `undefined`. The main lesson here is: do not use `this` in `data` functions. In your specific case, it would have been an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

in `this.data`, `this.count` is probably not yet set at the time when you try to reference it in `this.currentTranslation.chinese`. What I mean with this is that if you define an object, the property isn't set when you are still in the "creation" phase. Therefore, you can't reference the object itself in that step to reuse properties you defined above your current property.

```js
obj = {
   a: 1,
   b: obj.a + 1
}
```

This will give you

> Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined

You'd have to do this:

```js
obj = {
   a: 1,
}
obj.b = obj.a + 1
```

In Vue you can use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example).

```js
import flashcards from '../flashcards/flashcards.json';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        correctClickHandler() {
            this.setNextTranslation()
        },
        incorrectClickHandler() {
            this.setNextTranslation()
        },
        setNextTranslation() {
            this.count++
        }

    },
    computed: {
        // a computed getter
        chineseTranslation() {
            return flashcards[this.count].traditional
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not that `count` is not set. `this` is the function context. If you really need access to the component instance inside `data`, you can assign the current scope to it, but I wouldn't recommend it as a general practice as it's likely to create even more confusion for future devs having to work with that code.

Comment: Sure, it isn't. If you define an object, the property isn't set when you are still in the "creation" phase. Therefore, you can't reference the object itself in that step to reuse properties you defined above your current property.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I must have deleted one brace too much.

Comment: What I don't agree with from your answer is that you're suggesting it's a timing problem, which is not the case. It's a targeting problem. So even if you wrap everything inside a `setTimeout`, `count` won't be set later on `data`'s `this`.

Comment: It is both what you say in your answer and what I tried to describe, yet probably not as good as you did in your answer. It is not so much the actual timing but the place in the code. Maybe, there is a better way to describe that. I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: I understood your argument when you made it. And I agree with it, except for the case of [getter/setter](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/257Lshyc/)s. And, to be specific, a `computed` is exactly that: a getter/setter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247592/discussion-between-tao-and-shaedrich).